# How do you convert the following optimization problem with LMI constraints from the standard form given to the Semi Definite Programming(SDP) form?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming, linear-matrix-inequality

We are currently working on an engineering project involving convex optimization. The project relates to a low earth orbit spacecraft rendezvous. In the course of this project, we are required to convert an optimization problem given in the standard form to semidefinite programming or SDP form. Stating the problem below:

$$ \displaystyle \min_{\epsilon,\delta,X,Y,R,Q} \mu  $$

such that the following matrix inequalities
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
   \Omega & XE_1^T +Y^TG^T & Y^T & X \\
     *    & -\epsilon I    & 0   & 0  \\      
     *    &    *           & -R  & 0  \\
     *    &    *           & *   & -Q  \\
    \end{bmatrix}
            \leqq 0,                               $$

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-\delta I & X_eo^T\\
* & -X
\end{bmatrix} 
    \leqq 0, $$
and
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-X+v\delta I & 0 & 0 \\
 * & -\mu I & Y \\
 * & * & -vI \\
 \end{bmatrix} 
 \leqq 0 $$
hold. This is the standard form we have.

We would like to convert this to SDP form given below.

$$ \displaystyle \min_{X, \epsilon, H^n} \langle X, M_0 \rangle_F 
\ \ \mathrm{s.t.}\ \ \ l_s \le \langle X, M_s \rangle_F \le u_s,\ s = 1 \dots p,$$
where the angular brackets denote Frobenius Inner Product and where $ M_0,M_1,\dots,M_p \ \in \ H^n $, and $(l_s,u_s)$ are pairs of extended real numbers such that $-\infty\le l_s\le u_s\le\infty$ for all $s=1,\ldots,p$.

Is there any way in which the above-mentioned conversion can be carried out?

Comment: Why would you like to perform such a transformation? I also suspect few typos in your post which I have corrected.

Comment: @KBS We are using an algorithm that requires the problem in SDP form.

Comment: In this case you can just dualize the optimization problem to get the SDP problem in primal form.

Comment: @KBS Are there any references to do the same?

Comment: Any lecture notes or book on SDP problems. For instance, https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs.cmu.edu/academic/class/15859-f11/www/notes/lecture12.pdf. I can help but some information on the variables $\epsilon,\delta,X,Y,R$ and $Q$ are missing. Are they all positive (semi)definite? What is $\Omega$? Please also clarify all the other matrices and scalars which are data of the problem.